# I am tring to make a simple captcha in PHP, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, captcha

I am trying to make a simple captcha in PHP just for learning purpose, not converting the string into image as of now, I can't figure what I am doing wrong? I am not even able to verify the code, it's giving string didn't match every time

Here's the code

```
    <?php


    $var = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuywxyz1234567890';

    $random = str_shuffle($var);

    $captcha = substr($random,0,10);
    echo $captcha;


    if(isset($_POST['captcha'])){

    $check = $_POST['captcha'];
    if ($captcha==$check){
    echo 'Verified.';

    }else{echo 'string didn\'t match';}

    }

    ?>
    <form action="random.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="captcha"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Is something not working? Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: Errm, hate to brake it to you, but the whole point of a captcha is to prevent robots spamming. This does not do that. The robots will be laughing at you.

Comment: Captchas are supposed to be graphical in nature not textual! Robots can easily read texts.

Comment: "learning purpose , not converting the string into image as of now "

it's fine if you want to build something to learn. the thing is you are generating the captcha again while you are checking if POST'ed data is correct. How you should do is, bah! will explain below in a min.

Comment: 1 generate random string. 2 display it 3 user fills in form and submits it 4 generate random string 5 check new random string with posted value! See a problem here?

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are fair though. He is a newbie.

Comment: you somehow have to save the generated captcha like session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend this to use for captcha.

But i am correcting your code only for your `learning purpose`.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['captcha'])){

$check = $_POST['captcha'];
if ($_SESSION['captcha']==$check){
echo 'Verified.';

}else{echo 'string didn\'t match';}

}

$var = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuywxyz1234567890';

$random = str_shuffle($var);

$captcha = substr($random,0,10);
echo $captcha;
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;

?>
<form action="random.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="captcha"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx  Ashwin,  so i gues there is no way to do this without starting a session

Comment: you have to store the value of captcha text somehow.
And here i am doing this using session.

Comment: soo we need to store the value of $captcha because everytime we  click on submit the  page refreshes and $captcha 's value change . Sweeet :)

Answer (score 2):

TO Create a simple Captcha form, then here is a small guide:

===== 1 STEP ======
 in your FTP folder (where you need), put a font file (example: yourfont.ttf).
then create a file (called captcha.php) and paste the below code inside it (then put that captcha.php in the same ftp folder):

```
<?php session_start();

// generate random number and store in session
$randomnr = rand(1000, 9999);
$_SESSION['randomnr2'] = md5($randomnr);
//generate image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 38);
//colors:
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

// -------------      your fontname    -------------
//  example font http://www.webpagepublicity.com/free-fonts/a/Anklepants.ttf
$font = 'yourfont.ttf';

//draw text:
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 22, 24, $grey, $font, $randomnr);

imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 15, 26, $white, $font, $randomnr);

// prevent client side  caching
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revаlidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//send image to browser
header ("Content-type: image/gif");
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

===== 2 STEP ======

then in any page (where you want to implement the captcha) put this code somewhere inside that page (but of course, in the last part of this code, there is a sample PHP function to make an sample action if code is entered correctly. So you should know a more PHP programming to execute your desired functions when Captcha is correct):

```
<form method="post" action=""> <img src="captcha.php" />
<input class="input" type="text" name="codee" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
session_start();
if (md5($_POST['codee']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2']) { 
// here you  place code to be executed if the captcha test passes
  echo "YES. Do Something function1";
} 

else {  
 // here you  place code to be executed if the captcha test fails
  echo "No.  Do Something function2";
}
?>
```

Comment: I can easily hack this example by blocking access to "captcha.php". This way, $_SESSION['randomnr2'] is empty, so all I need to do is not to fill $_POST['codee']. When checking the captcha, there should be a check to make sure neither $_POST['codee'] nor $_SESSION['randomnr2'] are empty.